# javascript - missing parent element on nodelist when trying to add an event listener

Tags: javascript, html

Building a simple library for mastering javascript and I'm kinda stuck trying to get a custom attribute to basically provide a `ng-click` like functionality from AngularJS.

Also, the library is here [git](https://github.com/reap-r/rndr.js)

Can someone clone it and also have a look at what's possibly breaking avoiding the addition of the click handler

JS :

```
var utils = {
onClickWrapper: function(el) {
        el.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(node) {
          const parent = node.parentElement;
          if (node.attributes && node.hasAttribute("@click")) {
            var key = node.getAttribute("@click");
            var nodeClone = node.cloneNode(true);
            parent.removeChild(node)
            nodeClone.onclick = function(){
              alert('hello');
            }
            parent.appendChild(nodeClone);
          }
        });
      }  
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="app">
    <div>
      {{count}}
    </div>
    <button @click='increaseCount'>
      Add
    </button>
    <button @click='decreaseCount'>
      decrease
    </button>
  </div>
```

the `div.app` is send to the function for adding the event listeners. Right now just trying to get them to alert on the browser but that doesn't seem to be working.

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Is your javascript using a library? The syntax doesn't look familiar to me. Just wanted to know for sure before posting an answer

Comment: @YAHsaves I am creating a library for templating data like VueJs or AngularJS 1 does. The function definition you see is inside an Object.

Comment: The code you posted works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/acgrh2o5/

Comment: ..., then i've messed up something else, 
can you clone github.com/reap-r/rndr.js and try seeing what else could've gone wrong?